# how to compare 2 strings by each characters in perl

Tags: string, perl, string-comparison

basically I want to compare

```
$a = "ABCDE";
$b = "--(-)-";
```

and get output CE.

i.e where ever parentheses occur the characters of $a should be taken.

Comment: What about `$a='ABC';` and `$b='-----)(';`

Answer (score 4):

One of the rare uses of the bitwise or-operator.

```
# magic happens here  ↓
perl -E'say (("ABCDE" | "--(-)-" =~ tr/-()/\377\000/r) =~ tr/\377//dr)'
```

prints `CE`.

Use this for golfing purposes only, [AHA’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561381) is much more maintainable.

Comment: With some explanation, that could be an interesting answer.

Comment: One limitation: It can't be used if the input can contain characters 255 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

Simple regex and [pos](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html) solution:

```
my $str = "ABCDE";
my $pat = "--(-)-";

my @list;
while ($pat =~ /(?=[()])/g) {
    last if pos($pat) > length($str);  # Required to prevent matching outside $x
    my $char = substr($str, pos($y), 1); 
    push @list, $char;
}
print @list;
```

Note the use of lookahead to get the position before the matching character.

Combined with Axeman's use of the [`@-`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@LAST_MATCH_START) variable we can get an alternative loop:

```
while ($pat =~ /[()]/g) {
    last if $-[0] > length($str);
    my $char = substr($str, $-[0], 1);
    push @list, $char;
}
```

This is pretty much mentioned in [the documentation for `@-`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@LAST_MATCH_START):

```
After a match against some variable $var :
....
$& is the same as substr($var, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0])
```

In other words, the matched string `$&` equals that substring expression. If you replace `$var` with another string, you would get the characters matching the same positions.

In my example, the expression `$+[0] - $-[0]` (offset of end of match minus offset of start of match) would be 1, since that is the max length of the matching regex.

QED.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to accomplish using [`each_array`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils#each_array-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-...), [`each_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils#each_arrayref-LIST) or [`pairwise`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils#pairwise-BLOCK-ARRAY1-ARRAY2) from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util      qw( min );
use List::MoreUtils qw( each_array );

my $string        = 'ABCDE';
my $pattern       = '--(-)-';
my @string_chars  = split //, $string;
my @pattern_chars = split //, $pattern;

# Equalise length
my $min_length = min $#string_chars, $#pattern_chars;
$#string_chars = $#pattern_chars = $min_length;

my $ea = each_array @string_chars, @pattern_chars;
while ( my ( $string_char, $pattern_char ) = $ea->() ) {
    print $string_char if $pattern_char =~ /[()]/;
}
```

Using [`pairwise`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils#pairwise-BLOCK-ARRAY1-ARRAY2):

```
{
    no warnings qw( once );
    print pairwise {
        $a if $b =~ /[()]/;
    } @string_chars, @pattern_chars;
}
```

Without using [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils):

```
for ( 0 .. $#string_chars ) {
    print $string_chars[$_] if $pattern_chars[$_] =~ /[()]/;
}
```

**Thanks to *[TLP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp)*** for discovering the *set `$#`* technique without which this solution will have been longer and complicated. :-)

Comment: Does not compensate for when pattern string is longer than matching string, though.

Comment: `use List::Util qw(min); my $min_length = min $#string_chars, $#pattern_chars;` perhaps.

Comment: *[TLP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp)*: Updated my answer. Thank you. :-)

Comment: No problem. I discovered a cute technique.. if you set the array max index, e.g. `$#pattern_chars = $min`, it truncates the array. Not sure if it is good practice, but it seems to work.

Comment: Actually, it's mentioned in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) as a legitimate thing to do: `Assigning to $#days actually changes the length of the array. `

Comment: *[TLP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp)*: Excellent! Thank you for sharing that technique. I have updated my answer again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This uses the idea that you can scan one string for positions and just take the values of the other strings. `@s` is a reusable product.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub chars {
    my $source = shift;
    return unless @_;
    my @chars  = map { substr( $source, $_, 1 ) } @_;
    return wantarray ? @chars, join( '', @chars );
}

my $a = "ABCDE";
my $b = "--(-)-";

my @s;
push @s, @- while $b =~ m/[()]/g;
my $res = chars( $a, @s );
```

Answer (score 2):

Way faster than all the solutions except daxim's, and almost as fast as daxim's without preventing the use of characters 255 and above:

```
my $pat = $b =~ s/[^()]/.?/gr =~ s/[()]/(.?)/gr
my $c = join '', $a =~ /^$pat/s;
```

It changes

```
---(-)-
```

to

```
.?.?.?(.?).?(.?).?
```

Then uses the result as regex pattern to extract the desired characters.

Comment: Very close -- this fails on the given input.  You need to truncate $b to the length of $a before converting $b to a regex.

Comment: @pilcrow, I thought they were the same length, oops. Fixed. Didn't even need to truncate.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "ABCDE";
my $b = "--(-)-";
my ($i, $c, $x, $y) = 0;

$c .= $y =~ /\(|\)/ ? $x : "" while ($x = substr $a, $i, 1) && ($y = substr $b, $i++, 1);

print "$c\n";
```